# Handling static files when when upgrading an application

Tags: c#, windows-installer

My application has a number of static files (SQLite DB, User settings file) that are deployed with the application.

When publishing a new version, I'd like to replace the DLL's, but retain the users static files. I'm intending to use InstallShield LE, but open to other suggestions to create the installer.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't think the LE version supports this. You could use WIX which does, or you could just create the files in the user's App Data folder at application startup (rather than deploying them). The downside is that they won't be removed on uninstall.

Comment: Wow, InstallShield LE does not support this? What a piece of junk. There is *never* a reason for an upgrade to wipe out a user's files. Run, don't walk, to a different installer toolchain.